# Using Double.parseDouble( ) within I/O

Tags: java, io, increment

I'm trying to write a program that gets a series of five double String values from a user and then attempt to convert those Strings to a double using the `Double.parseDouble()` method. The trouble I'm having is that I have to enter two values before the next "`Please enter a number`" pops up. Here is the output I've been getting:

```
Please enter a number 1: 4
3
Please enter a number 2: 5
4
Please enter a number 3: 3
4
Please enter a number 4: 5
6
Please enter a number 5: 4
2
The average is: 3.8
```

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class theman {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    // Variables
        int counter;
        int userEntries = 5;
        double sum = 0;


        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);


    // Creating a new Scanner
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Loop for the five entries    
        for (counter = 1; counter <= userEntries; counter++) {
            String input = "";
            System.out.print("Please enter a number " + counter + ": ");
            input = br.readLine();
            double number = Double.parseDouble(input);
            sum += scanner.nextDouble();
        }   

    // Print statements
        System.out.println("The average is: " + sum / userEntries);


    } // End of method header
} // End of class header
```

What is the best way to correct this problem? I'm assuming it's because of the `sum += scanner.nextDouble();` but I need it to increment so I really can't delete it.

Comment: You are trying to read every number twice.  I suggest you only read one number at a time. either use readLine() & parseDouble OR use scanner.nextDouble().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have the double, so there's no need to use `Scanner.nextDouble()`. The `nextDouble()` method scans the next token of the input as a double. What you should be doing is `sum += number`.

Comment: ahhh.. I knew the problem lied within that area. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
final int userEntries = 2;
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
double sum = 0.0;

for (int counter = 1; counter <= userEntries; ++counter) {
    System.out.printf("Please enter a number %d: ", counter);
    sum += in.nextDouble();
}

System.out.printf("The average is: %.2f%n", sum / userEntries);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's an updated code -

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class theman {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    // Variables
    int counter;
    int userEntries = 5;
    double sum = 0;

    // Creating a new Scanner
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Loop for the five entries
    for (counter = 1; counter <= userEntries; counter++) {
         System.out.print("Please enter a number " + counter + ": ");
         sum += scanner.nextDouble();
    }

    // Print statements
    System.out.println("The average is: " + sum / userEntries);


  } // End of method header
} // End of class header
```

Comment: Merely fixing the code isn't much of an answer.  You are expecting readers to look through all of your code and visually distinguish the differences from the original question's code.  Explain what the original code did wrong, and explain your changes.